# FTP issues from .NET to LAMP : Index and Length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: ftp, lamp

Our system is a basic LAMP stack. On our site we've setup a standard FTP directory and sent the ftp details onto a supplier to upload xml stock files hourly. I'm not 100% sure what their system is but I suspect its .net asp/c#. When they try upload via their automated system they receiving the following error in their log files -

> Index and Length must refer to a location within the string. Paramater
>   name: length

They can't tell us any more info and they saying the problem lies on our side. However ftp seems to be working perfectly fine to that directory as far as our testing has gone. I'm realy not sure of the best way to proceed.

So is there anyone experienced with .net and or FTP transfering files from .net environment to PHP linux environment that knows of the problem and how to get around it?

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1:
Below is the supplier's code that is being used to upload the file:

```
dataset.WriteXml("c:\stock.xml")
oCM = oCnM
Connect("ftp.domain.com", "21", "user@domain.com", "password123")
GoHome()
oFTP.FtpPutFile("c:\stock.xml", "stock.xml", FileLen("c:\stock.xml"))
EventLog.WriteEntry("web pastelQ2 export started step5", "")
```

Comment: Removed all .NET tags, as that code is not .NET based. Please try to capture network packets and see what's up on the wire. If you can confirm your FTP server is correct, then ask them to fix the client side code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure the problem is not related to FTP nor LAMP/NET differences. The error message itself looks as .NET exception catch-ed by some outer guard (index error while manipulating with string content).

Could they provide detailed stack trace? Without it, we have to guess forever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yury. I've edited the question to include the supplier's code. Does that help in any way?